# Can't update value into model generated by Constructor

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the OOP with the following example below. Can you please explain what am I doing wrong and why?

```js
var shoppingcartModel = function() {
    var _Cart = function() {
        return {
            totalPrice: {},
            products: []
        };
    }

    return {
        cart: _Cart,

        addProducts: function(product) {
            return _Cart().products.push(product);
        }
    };
};

var shoppingCart = shoppingcartModel()

console.log(shoppingCart.cart())

shoppingCart.addProducts('product1')
shoppingCart.addProducts('product2')

console.log(shoppingCart.cart())
```

Comment: `cart` will always return a brand-new Object with preemptied `totalPrice` and `products`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_Cart` is a function that *returns* an object, not an object itself. Whenever you call `Cart_()`, including in `addProducts`, you create a new object, so whatever you push to one of the old objects is disregarded because no reference to the old object remains.

Try something like this instead:

```js
var shoppingcartModel = function() {
  const cart = {
    totalPrice: {},
    products: []
  };
  return {
    cart,
    addProducts: function(product) {
      return cart.products.push(product);
    }
  };
};

var shoppingCart = shoppingcartModel()

console.log(shoppingCart.cart)

shoppingCart.addProducts('product1')
shoppingCart.addProducts('product2')

console.log(shoppingCart.cart)
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer it actually covers the principal logic, but I do have a case where test requires Cart to be a function, maybe you can clarify how should it work in this case?

Comment: That's a pretty silly/arbitrary case - ignore it if at all possible, though I suppose you could turn it into a getter function for an object in the `shoppingcartModel` scope.